# gitlab issue- not able to save application after changing the context-root

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am working on a **ADF application**,with **jdeveloper**. I have to change context root of the application, the project is a **git repository**. After changing the context root, I am unable to save the project. Below is the issue:
**Issue** - Unable to save /Users/{username}/gitlab/{project name}/ViewController/ViewController.jpr (The project /Users/{username}/gitlab/{project name}/ViewController/ViewController.jpr is in a merge conflict state.  Please resolve the merge conflicts in the project file before attempting to save further changes.).

Comment: Please make your question readable. I suggest reading [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This seems like an error log rather than a question. Please provide a context to your problem so that others at StackOverflow can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know the exact cause of this. But i have gone through same case and it seems like it is caused due to some conflict in project properties.
 So i would recommend you to right click on viewcontroller go to **properties> Java EE application** and there instead of making changes directly in default project properties. Use **customized settings** option given by JDeveloper and change your context-root there. It wont cause any conflict there.

[image: Screenshot customized Java EE Aplication settings]

Comment: Also i dont think this issue is linked to gitlab.